# Changing product name for application xcode 4.5.2

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.5

I am changing the current product name of my iOS application in xcode to a new name by  navigating to target build settings and then change the product name.

However, when I run the project after changing the product name the emulator shows a black window and the project is not loading.

Where am I wrong ? I haven't done any backup and I think the project is lost or something is not loading.. did someone ran in the same issue or know whats not turning right ?

Comment: First try to reset the simulator and also clean the build for project and then try to rebuild the project again will solve the problem :)

Comment: how to reset the emulator ?

Comment: i selected the project then in product clean after clean i build but the screen remains black

Comment: just open simulator and click on iOS Simulator > reset content and settings... option will bring one popup telling or warning you about resetting of simulator. Click jon reset button and done :)

Comment: that you wolvorin its working like charm :)

Comment: glade to help you out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clean and reset the simulator.

For reset the simulator follow the steps below.

1. just open the simulator.
2. Then click on iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings ...
   [image]
3. This will bring the popup window showin the warning about resetting the simulator and ask for your conformation.
   [image]
4. just click on reset button.
5. And Done.